# Stringmethods problems

Tags: c#, methods

I've got 2 Methods and i cant get the right answer.

1. Method we need to check if the characters are same in the string, and there need to be same.
   e.g.:

   s="******" return true

   s="***-**" return false

Here is why I tried:

```
static bool SindAlleZeichenGleich(string s)
        {
            if (s.Contains("*")) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If there is any another character is gives still true and that is not right.

1. Methode: We need to make the first letter big and the second low, and it should keep doing it until the string is done.

e.g.:

"abcde" return "AbCdE"

This is what I tried:

```
static string ToggleCharacters(string s)
        {


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);

        }
```

The problem is im only getting the first letter big others are still small.

Comment: you'll need to check the entire string character by character and not just for `Contains("*")`

Comment: OK, you have an assignment, you don't know how to write the program, and you're stuck with two programs that do nothing like what the assignment says.  That's a story, not a question. What's your specific question? Are you asking people to do your homework for you?

Comment: For your first problem: start with the basics. What if the string is null? What if it is empty? What if it contains a single character?  Solve those problems first.  Now you have a smaller problem to solve: how can you tell if a string is all the same character, if it has two or more characters?  Well, that is the same as answering the question "are all the characters equal to the first character?"  Can you see how to answer that question?

Comment: Based on what you've tried so far, I suspect that you do not know what a loop is. Do you know what a loop is?

Comment: Yes i know i can go through the loop and get the string

Comment: A loop is necessary to look at each character in the string. Which you need to do to solve either of these problems, yes?

Comment: Yes i got it thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks 4 help.

1. Methode I went through the whole string so i could know which characters are in the string.

   ```
   static bool SindAlleZeichenGleich(string s)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
       {
           if (s[i] != s[0])
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
       if(s == "")
       {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Good. But instead of if s == “”, check out IsNullOrEmpty() and make that your first test

Comment: Why does it return false if the string is empty?    The condition is **every character in the string is equal to every other character**. For an empty string, that condition is **true**, not **false**.  In an empty string it is certainly true that of zero characters, zero of them are equal to each other. If the number of equal characters is the same as the number of characters then the condition is met, right?

Comment: As a beginner, you are right to use a `for` loop to solve this problem.  As you become a more confident programmer you can start using more advanced tools. For example, you could write this program `foreach(char c in s) { if (c != s[0]) return false; } return true;`, and now you don't have an indexer to worry about. You could also write your program very concisely as `static bool MyMethod(string s) => !((s??"").Any(c=>c!=s[0]));`  But walk before you try to run!

Comment: For the other one, look at the % operator. And consider that strings are immutable (cannot be changed). So while s = s + charVar; might be ok, s[1] = charVar; is not. You can also look at StringBuilder.